# Google Sheets hyperlink to Cell doesn't work on Android or iOS Sheets App

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I've seen this question in the site a couple times but the ones i found are from a couple years ago and dont seem to get to a solution.
Anyway, i have a spreadsheet that generates hyperlinks to cells in a different spreadsheet. Works perfectly on the web but not on Android or iOS Google Sheets Apps as it would only open the correct spreadsheet but will not take me to the specified cell.

This is the function that i'm using:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE/edit#gid=ID_NUMBER
_HERE&range=G2")
```

on the web it takes me to cell G2 of the spreadsheet. But on mobile it just opens the spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

While on IOS mobile or tablet, you need to click the link twice until a pop up appears and you then select “open link” as opposed to clicking the link displayed in the formula bar at the bottom of your screen (which opens up a new browser tab and ignores the specified sheet and range). When you click “open link” is keeps you within the Sheets app, and it will take you to the specific cell range in your hyperlink and will be highlighted (just like on your desktop).

It still is buggy at times (I won’t dig into that), but will work in your scenario.